# R code halts in for loop no error message

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm working on a segment of R code which is a for loop that reads in columns from a collection of .csv files the paths of which are compiled in a file path directory I've made.  As it reads in each file it stores four different columns into four different grand tables within my working environment.
I'm trying to make part of code calculates the monthly average for each month then stores it in a new column so that I can use it to replace missing data points and this involves a couple more for loops for mapping the subset of the aggregate table.
All this ends up being four nested for loops which handles a great deal of data at once before overwriting with the next large file.
After incorporating the nested 3 loops which build the monthly average vector the code started halting as soon as it tries to read in the data file with no error message it just looks like this.

[halted code no errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Elp2.png)

if I add show_col_types = FALSE to the read_csv it looks like this instead still halting the code.

[halted code with show_col_types = FALSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1ORP.png)

I can't include the data or much of the code because my company will not allow it but I would appreciate any input since there isn't any error message I can google.  Thanks!

Comment: Note the little red stop icon in the upper right. There is no error. The code is still running. 4 nested loops (if the inner loops are at all computationally intensive) can take a long time to run.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.